# When I convert a string to an integer how can I make it so I can multiply it?

Tags: java, string, netbeans, integer

So basically what I did is I converted the string to an integer and now I want to make it so whatever number the user enters will be multiplied by 7.

```
        String strName;
        strName=this.txtInputDogName.getText();
        String strAge;
        strAge=this.txtInputDogAge.getText();
        int foo;
        foo = Integer.parseInt(strAge);
        int strAge = (strAge*7);
        this.lblOutput.setText("Hello "+strName+"'s age in human years is "+strAge);
```

Comment: ... multiply `foo` by `7`?

Comment: You could try using your parsed int for the calculation instead of ignoring it: `foo * 7`

Comment: Yeah, why you created foo while you still try to multiply strAge?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define and assign to a variable on separate lines.

Instead of writing

```java
String strName;
strName=this.txtInputDogName.getText();
```

You can write it like this:

```java
String strName = this.txtInputDogName.getText();
```

And you dont need the variable `foo` at all. You can just use `parseInt`, multiply it by 7, and convert it to string.

Now the improved and correct version of your code is:

```java
String strName = this.txtInputDogName.getText();
String strAge = this.txtInputDogAge.getText();
strAge = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(strAge) * 7);
this.lblOutput.setText("Hello " + strName + "'s age in human years is " + strAge);
```

Comment: This won't compile. An `int` has no `toString` method.

Comment: @QBrute Hah, sorry I forgot that. I mainly use kotlin and you can do that in kotlin.